# Show that the function $ F(x,y) = (ax+\sin^2(x+y), ay +\cos^2(x+y))$ with $ a \in \mathbb{R} $ is Lipschitz continuous

Tags: multivariable-calculus, trigonometry, lipschitz-functions

Trying to prove that this function $ F: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 $ is Lipschitz continuous:
$ F(x,y) = (ax+\sin^2(x+y), ay +\cos^2(x+y))$ with $ a \in \mathbb{R} $

So I am trying to proove that we can find $k$ such as:
$ d( f(x,y),f(t,z) \leq k d( (x,y)(t,z)) $

$ \sqrt{ [at + \sin^2(t + z) - ax - \sin^2(x + y)]^2 +[az + \cos^2(t + z)-ay - \cos^2(x + y)]^2} \\ \leq k   (\sqrt{(t-x)^2 +(z-y)^2})   $

But I can't find the trick.
Any idea?

Comment: mean-value theorem: show $F$ has bounded first derivative.

Comment: great. But how to generalize with 2 variables: I compute the 2 partial derivatives, right?

Comment: Look at all 4 partial derivatives (search mean-value inequality, you'll see free appropriate results)

Comment: Got it, tks! If that was an answer, I would have accepted it